# I Cannot Close the UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uiview

I do like:

```
**//some methods of myButton inheried from UIButton**

-(void)timerFireMethod:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
        UIAlertView *alert = [ [ UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"alerts" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
        [alert show];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(timerFireMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
     [timer invalidate];
}
```

1)I touch the but until showing the uialertview, then I go to click the cancel button of the uialertview, but the uialertview doesn't close.

2)If I turn `[timer invalidate];` into `//[timer invalidate];`

and do like as I did in the above code, the uialertview can close.

Why?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: I have resolved my question by change "repeats:NO" to "repeats:YES".

Answer (score 0):

You're not releasing the alert view.

```
    UIAlertView *alert = [ [ UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"hello" message:@"alerts" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
    [alert show];
    [alert release]; // <-- important
```